# Blink CardView does not start [Object Animator, Android]

Tags: android, kotlin, animation, objectanimator

today I'm trying to make blink effect in my CardView... Works if I put `backgroundColor` but does not if I use `strokeColor`. I've followed [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@Syex/how-to-add-a-flashing-border-to-cardview-aaf35b3ece2b) to make it real but is not working really... How can I change to make this effect correctly?

```
 private fun createBlinkEffect() {

    val animator = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(mCardView,
        "strokeColor",
        ContextCompat.getColor(this, COLOR.WHITE),
        ContextCompat.getColor(this, COLOR.RED))

    animator.duration = 400
    animator.setEvaluator(ArgbEvaluator())
    animator.repeatMode = ValueAnimator.REVERSE
    animator.repeatCount = ValueAnimator.INFINITE
    animator.start()
}
```

this is my `layout_item`

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mCardView"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="152dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    app:strokeWidth="2dp"
    app:strokeColor="@android:color/transparent"
    app:cardCornerRadius="12dp">
```

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

That's it!

```
private fun createBlinkEffect() {
        ObjectAnimator.ofArgb(mCardView,
            "strokeColor",
            ContextCompat.getColor(this, Color.RED)).apply {
            duration = 500
            repeatCount = Animation.INFINITE
            addUpdateListener { mCardView.invalidate() }
            start()
        }
    }
```

Ps. Remember use `MaterialCardView` instead `CardView` and set a default `strokeWidth` and `strokeColor`